# Filtering XML attributes (fn:node-name vs. fn:name)

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xquery

Using XQuery (in eXist-db 2.2), I am trying to process a set of XML elements and remove a single attribute from each element in the result set.

Example XML:

```
<results xmlns:abc="http://example.org">
    <abc:element1 abc:selected="false" type="Class"/>
    <abc:element2 abc:selected="false" type="Property"/>        
</results>
```

The attribute to be removed is `@abc:selected`. My question is, what is the difference between filtering an attribute set by fn:name vs. fn:node-name, when the attribute has an xs:QName?

If I use fn:node-name and compare to the xs:QName of the attribute, then `@abc:selected` is not removed.

XQuery:

```
for $r in $results
let $name := node-name($r)
return
    element {$name} {
        $r/@*[node-name(.) != xs:QName('abc:selected')]             
    }
```

Result:

```
<results xmlns:abc="http://example.org">
    <abc:element1 abc:selected="false" type="Class"/>
    <abc:element2 abc:selected="false" type="Property"/>        
</results>
```

However, if I use fn:name and compare to the string value of the attribute, then `@abc:selected` is successfully removed.

XQuery:

```
for $r in $results
let $name := node-name($r)
return
    element {$name} {
        $r/@*[name(.) != 'abc:selected']
    }
```

Result:

```
<results xmlns:abc="http://example.org">
    <abc:element1 type="Class"/>
    <abc:element2 type="Property"/>        
</results>
```

What is the difference here? Why doesn't the first approach, with fn:node-name and xs:QName, work as I expect it to?

Comment: In the interest of not reinventing the wheel you should take a look at Priscilla's FunctX stuff. Just as you require, she has a function for removing an attribute (amongst others): http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_remove-attributes.html

Comment: @adamretter Indeed, this is what I was using, but kept getting type and cardinality errors, so opted for a temporary solution.

Comment: well you may have been better opening a Q&A about that and getting that resolved...

Comment: In eXist 2.2 and eXist 2.3, as well as BaseX 8.2.1 `$r/@*[name(.) != 'abc:selected']` removes `abc:selected="false"`, contrary to what @tat writes. It is the same with `$r/@*[name(.) != 'abc:selected']`, so no problem here. With `$r/@*[node-name(.) ne QName('http://example.org', 'selected')]` there is a difference, in that the attribute is removed in eXist 2.3 (the develop version, soon to be released as 2.3), but not in eXist 2.2 (it is also removed in BaseX 8.2.1).

Comment: @JensØstergaardPetersen, thanks, good to know! I'm not sure what you mean by "contrary to," however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that isn't the proper way to create the expected `xs:QName` instance. This expression `xs:QName('abc:selected')` is throwing error *"No namespace declared for prefix abc"* for me (tested in BaseX).

You can use `fn:QName()` which return `xs:QName` instance instead, and that should properly remove `abc:selected` attributes :

```
for $r in $results
let $name := node-name($r)
return
    element {$name} {
        $r/@*[node-name(.) ne QName('http://example.org', 'selected')]             
    }
```